# Does anyone really uses G-WAN web server?

Tags: webserver, g-wan

Besides impressing benchmarks,

does anyone really uses G-WAN web server?

(except of cource gwan.ch and trustleap.com)

Comment: The developer is a genius clearly (read the gwan about), and beyond creating an absolutely insanely fast, massively scalable application server, seems to have one thing in mind: massive profit. An Open source project G-WAN is not, which is fine, G-WAN developer is Bill Gates to (Nginx, Apache, Node.js, etc.) Linus Torvolds. G-WAN's forum has been closed, apparently due to FUDites taking exception to his bank account. I too was impressed with the benchmarks, but the open source alternatives are more than sufficient for my needs...

Comment: Nope. I've not used in a production enviroment due this facts: not FreeSoftware or OpenSource, just one tech developer on the team, very little comunity, you just can receive support by paying $$, really new on the market, not well tested, unkown bussines that are using it in production enviroments and the fact that the main developer is *very* aggresive and says that his product is the best in all the aspects. I agree with virtualeyes about the hungry of massive profits. There are much more better solutions out there, well tested and with a greater comunity.

Answer (score 12):

G-WAN is a freeware, that means that people are not under the obligation of paying a license to use it for commercial purposes.

Having participated to write some of their code, I am aware of Web sites using G-WAN for different applications platforms:

- auctions
- advertising
- yellow pages
- social network
- geographic maps
- multimedia streaming
- trading.

But this is merely my personal experience. I must say that G-WAN has allowed me to do things that could not be done with other servers like:

- using cheap virtual servers where I would have had to use dedicated servers
- using the same Web server to create applications in different languages
- creating applications which rely on different programming languages
- test code modifications without having to redeploy packages or modify configurations
  -etc.

G-WAN, at least for me, has been a game-changer.

I do not understand the comment of "Virtualeyes" since my customers did not pay a dime to the G-WAN author. I just paid him 149 CHF, not because I was obliged to do it but rather because I wanted to thank him for the hard work.

By the way, that's Linus Torvalds, not *"Linus Torvolds"*.

Comment: Do you have any URLs I could see of sites that use G-WAN?